# Replace 173 Wh lead acid battery with 20000 mAh power bank

Tags: backup, powerbanks

I have an [APC BX1100C](https://www.apc.com/shop/in/en/products/APC-Back-UPS-1100VA-230V-without-auto-shutdown-software-India/P-BX1100C-IN) 173 Wh UPS that I use for my computer. I also have a 20000 mAh power bank with output voltage of 5 V.

What do I need to do to replace UPS battery with this power bank? Is this power bank capable of replacing the ups battery? UPS load is 50 W.

Comment: What is the UPS battery voltage? Is it 5V? How much amps the powerbank can provide? How much amps the UPs needs? If you can answer those questions, maybe you will see if it is possible or not. My initial assumption is no, it can't replace UPS battery.

Comment: Is your 20000 mAh at 5 V (100 Wh), or is it the trick they usually pull of stating the capacity at the nominal cell voltage 3.7 V (74 Wh)?

Comment: @colin it's 20000mah/72wh, total output 5v/2.1A

Comment: @Justme ups output: 230V,5A.

Comment: You never said the UPS battery voltage or other ratings of the UPS battery. We still can't know if you can replace something unknown with something else. Take your time to make sure you have given all the info requested or it will be impossible to answer.

Comment: The 20000 mAh stated capacity is probably at the native Lithium Ion voltage of 3.7V. That translates to 14800 mAh at 5V. Also, you can't provide 50W with a ~10W power supply (5V at 2.1A). So, this can never work. Capacities of power banks are also often grossly overstated by their sellers.

Answer (score 1):

UPS usually uses a 12 volt lead acid battery.  The site you linked to says the UPS uses a lead acid battery.  It doesn't say it's 12V, but they usually are.

It is specified as 173 watt hours. That's something like 14 amperes at 12V for one hour.

Your power bank is 20 ampere hours.  Giving it the benefit of the doubt, that would be 100 ampere hours (5V at 20 A for one hour.)  More likely, it's 74 watt hours (3.7V at 20A for one hour.)

That's quite a bit less than the original battery.

The UPS expects 12V from the battery.  You'd have to use a boost converter to go from 5V to 12V.  You'll lose power that way, and runtime.

It is also unlikely that the powerbank could deliver the needed current.  It would take more than twice as much current from the power bank to boost it from 5V to 12V.  It is unlikely that the power bank can supply the needed current.  Power banks usually have USB connectors.  I'm pretty sure the USB connector itself would start melting from the high current if the power bank would deliver it.

**As a practical thing, you cannot use your powerbank in your UPS.**

---

Look at it this way:

To get 230VAC from 5V, you have boost the voltage by a factor of 46.

To get the required current (5A) at 230VAC, you have to put in 46 times as much current on the low side.

Your power bank would have to deliver 230 amperes at 5V to the boost converter to get the needed 12V.

Comment: Where you write "A" or "ampere" in the first three sentences, you alsmost certainly mean Ah.

Comment: Nope.  I said ampere hours where I meant ampere hours, and amperes where I meant amperes.

Comment: In the first case you mentioned you're right. However I still don't think this is correct: "100 ampere hours (5V at 20A)" and "74 watt hours (3.7V at 20A)".

Comment: The "for one hour" was implicit.

Comment: I see, It's less confusing now ;-)